# Printing From PDA 3505 Handheld Printer With Serial Port as Interface By Using Cordova

Tags: serial-communication, thermal-printer

I'm developing an Android App for printing a receipt from POS device (PDA3505 HandHeld Built in Printer) thermal Printer by using IONIC/CORDOVA, I stacked totally,IONIC/CORDOVA provides Serial Communication plugin but when I use it it detects other devices from Serial Ports but not the printer itself. I tried 'lsusb' command from linux shell to list all devices but it excludes the printer itself. So How can I achieve the goal ?

Note: Communication Interface for that printer is Serial Communication (RS232)

Comment: Have you managed to make the app print texts? I have the same device and can't make it work

Comment: @AlexandruPufan Not yet

Comment: Any luck? I also have a pre-existing Ionic app that I would like to use with the PDA3505. I attempted building a Cordova plugin but it didn't go very well the first time.

Comment: @AmaniChang'a I've been able to get the device printing from Cordova, Im now battling with the buffer not being cleared and prints being repeated. It might be a lack of knowledge of the Java programming lang. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi Sumo , Can you share how you managed to print form cordova ? It will be my pleasure...